# How to get a reference to a prefab asset in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, serialization, deserialization, prefab

I have the following class

```cs
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    
    public class PixelSystem
    {
        public GameObject pixelPrefab;
        public Texture2D[] style;
        public List<Chunk> chunks;
        public GameObject mGameObject;
        public PixelSystem(GameObject _mGameObject)
        {
            mGameObject = _mGameObject;
            chunks = new List<Chunk>();
        }
    }
```

`Chunk` and `Pixel` are structs but I don't think they are relevant.

I would like `pixelPrefab` and `style` to be serialized but cannot seem to be able to make that work. This script is not attatched to a GameObject.

I have looked into getting the assets at runtime with `Resources` or `Addressables` but I would like to be able to set these fields from the editor.

I have tried making the class inherit from `MonoBehaviour` and having `[SerializeField] public GameObject pixelPrefab;` and `[SerializeField] public Texture2D[] style;`, but the result of this is that `pixelPrefab` is settable from the editor but instead of showing `style` it shows `mGameObject`, for some reason...  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
**Edit:** Turns out that the `[SerializeFields]` do nothing here, the result is the same without them.

I've also tried puting `[System.Serializable]` before the class, but as far as I can tell this does nothing at all.

Someone plz help.

**Edit:**

Due to some misunerstandings I would like to clarify a few things:

1. I have the prefab asset already, it is in my assets folder not in my scene, creating the assets is not the problem.
2. `pixelPrefab` would work fine as a `static` property, however, `style` would not.
3. Style only needs serializing for a default value and so is not a priority.
4. This code is very incomplete, the constructor is incomplete, I want an answer to this qusetion before I spend time writing code that may be unusable.
5. I want to select the assets in the editior
6. I do not want to have a function that must be called before the classes are used, so that the assets are loaded
7. I do not want to load the assets each time they are referenced, so no `get {load();}`

This is what I want to see in the editor when I select my script:
[image: If you can see this the image probably failed to load but idk]

And this is the closest thing to what I want so far:
[image: If you can see this the image probably failed to load but idk]

Which I get by setting the class to inherit from `MonoBehaviour`, I'd rather not inherit from anything, and idk if you are meant to have `MonoBehaviour` classes that aren't attatched to gameObjects, but if this is necessary then so be it.

[complete .cs file here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eSvueD3rucdlsHEsD1Dt-gLi0Teg7qom/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things here. I'm going to assume this point is the most important:

> 5. I want to select the assets in the editior

So, in order to be able to do this, every field you want to see has to be able to be serialized by Unity and also Unity needs to be able to draw the GUI for that thing. You said,

> I would like `pixelPrefab` and `style` to be serialized but cannot seem to be able to make that work.

and again here I'm taking "serialized" to really mean that you just want those fields exposed in the Editor so you can stick things into them. So when you give me the following snippet I immediately see several issues:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PixelSystem
{
    public GameObject pixelPrefab;
    public Texture2D[] style;
    public List<Chunk> chunks;
    public GameObject mGameObject;
    public PixelSystem(GameObject _mGameObject)
    {
        mGameObject = _mGameObject;
        chunks = new List<Chunk>();
    }
}
```

The first is that `PixelSystem` itself isn't serialized. You either need to tag the class with `[System.Serializable]` to use Unity's serializer or you need to inherit from something that Unity already knows should be serialized, like `Component` or `MonoBehaviour` (`MonoBehaviour` inherits `Component`). The issue with `Component` and subclasses is that they need to exist on a GameObject, so you can't `new` a `Component`, you have to `.AddComponent<YourComponent>()`.

Now as you've discovered, when you have your script inherit `MonoBehaviour`, you see

> that `pixelPrefab` is settable from the editor but instead of showing style it shows `mGameObject`, for some reason... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

And the reason it's showing `mGameObject` can be seen in your class' member variables:

```
public GameObject pixelPrefab;
public Texture2D[] style;
public List<Chunk> chunks;
public GameObject mGameObject;
```

You can see that `pixelPrefab` is a `public GameObject`. Great! (1) your class is inheriting `MonoBehaviour`, so Unity knows to serialize it, (2) `pixelPrefab` is `public`, so the Editor knows to show it, and `GameObject` is itself a serializable object that Unity knows how to draw, so the end result is that Unity adds `pixelPrefab` to the Editor GUI for your class.

Then you get to `style`, which is `public`, so the Editor knows it should show it, but it's an **array** and Unity doesn't know how to draw the Editor GUI for an array. It's an array of `Texture2D`, which it *does* know how to draw, but it doesn't know how to handle the array aspect, so it doesn't add `style` to your GUI.

Then you get to `chunks`, which is `public`, so the Editor knows it should show it, and it's a `List`, which Unity **does** know how to handle, but it's a List of `Chunk`, which I'm betting is not inheriting `MonoBehaviour` and is also not tagged with `[System.Serializable]`, so Unity doesn't know that it's supposed to be serializing `Chunk`. This means that it does know it's supposed to be drawing a list, but it think it's not supposed to be drawing any contents for the list, so it skips the list completely.

Finally you get to `public GameObject mGameObject`, which gets drawn for all the same reasons that `pixelPrefab` gets drawn, and finally you get what you see in the Editor in your last screenshot: Only `pixelPrefab` and `mGameObject` are drawn in your class GUI:

[image: OP's class in Editor]

So, what to do if you want to view your class in an Editor pane and you also want to see `pixelPrefab` and `style`?

1. Have something that can be serialized, like a `MonoBehavior`, hold a reference to `PixelSystem` OR have `PixelSystem` inherit `MonoBehavior`.
2. If `PixelSystem` is not a `MonoBehavior` then it needs to have `[System.Serializable]` on the line above `public class PixelSystem`.
3. Do what you've already done and have `public GameObject pixelPrefab`.
4. Convert `style` from an array to a list so Unity knows how to draw it.

You should wind up with the following:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]    
public class PixelSystem
{
    public GameObject pixelPrefab;
    public List<Texture2D> style = new List<Texture2D>();
    public List<Chunk> chunks;
    public GameObject mGameObject;
    public PixelSystem(GameObject _mGameObject)
    {
        mGameObject = _mGameObject;
        chunks = new List<Chunk>();
    }
}
```

You can also have `Chunk` be serialized and shown in your Editor pane if you tag that class with `[System.Serializable]`, and you only need the `[SerializeField]` tag for fields that aren't already `public`. You can still add that tag to public fields just like you can add `[System.Serializable]` to a `MonoBehaviour` but it's redundant. Not required.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try this hope this works. One thing however, in Unity's official documentation it says it **can** serialize an array of any other serializable type, and unity can serialize a `Texture2D`, in addition to this, when attatched to a gameobject as a component, a public `Texture2D[]` field does show up. So I think I must have misunderstood your explanation. Can you clarify?

Comment: I have tried with the following code
```cs
[System.Serializable]
public class PixelSystem
{
    public GameObject pixelPrefab;
    public Texture2D[] style;
    public List<Chunk> chunks;
    public GameObject mGameObject;
    public PixelSystem(GameObject _mGameObject)
    {
        mGameObject = _mGameObject;
        chunks = new List<Chunk>();
    }
}
```
But it shows nothing in the editor, does this work for you?

Comment: Link to my complete code in the question

Comment: @Jacob it can serialize an array but it can't draw the array in the Editor pane. Personally I don't know why it's any different than drawing a list but that's how it is. Regarding the changes to your script in the comments here, I don't know what is referencing the PixelSystem. If you have it on a GameObject and you stripped the MonoBehaviour inheritance then that's why it's not showing anything - you have to at least inherit Component to get it to display correctly when attached to a GameObject.

Comment: There is a screenshot in my question of it doing just that, also the prefab doesn’t show in the editor either, it shows neither

Comment: it can draw arrays in the editor pane try it with a monobehaviour attached to a game object

Comment: @Jacob You're not showing me the Component or MonoBehaviour that's holding your PixelSystem so I can't comment on why it's not showing up.

Comment: Its not being held by anything, its a standalone asset, nothing is using the PixelSystem class in my project, I would like to be able to set the default values in the inspector when I select the script asset, not when I select a gameobject.

Comment: The when it showed the prefab and mGameObject it was not attached to any gameobject, nor was it used by any script. That was simpy what came up when I selected the .cs asset

Comment: @Jacob - that's not how this works. You can't use the editor to set values for a script that hasn't been instantiated. Scripts in your Assets library are like items on Amazon's website. You can see what they are, you can see what they do, but you can't actually *DO* anything with them until you get an instance of that script. You can put the script on a GameObject, you can add one to a Prefab, but you don't get to set values or anything until you actually have a copy to interact with. The closest to what you're describing is a `ScriptableObject`, where instances live in the project as Assets.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand, even if there is no way to set values from the editor, is there a way to set the default value to my prefab?

Comment: @Jacob - you can try `Resources.Load()` in your constructor to assign the variable on construction, or you can make it a MonoBehavior and instantiate the script, in your scene or as a prefab, and set the prefabs manually on the instance. If you use `Resources.Load()` then the prefab has to be somewhere under a folder named Resources. There are other ways to load prefabs, but only `Resources.Load` will work in built versions of your game.

Comment: Thank you very much I will use Resources.Load(), would that work as a default value, or would it have to be asigned in a constructor?